# Need to satisfy 3 "AND" conditions in Excel

Tags: excel-2016

What Excel formula structure would I use if I need three "AND" conditions to be satisfied in order to yield a given output? I can only see how to do it with 2 "AND" conditions.

Thanks in advance for the community's assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest one AND() function in another one to meet your requirement.

For example, lets assume your conditions were:

```
A1=3 AND B1=6 AND C1=99
```

This can be written as follows:

```
=AND(A1=3, AND(B1=6, C1=99))
```